# Copy values to only certain types of sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy certain values from one 'Master' sheet, to certain multiple other sheets.

For example, I have 5 sheets in my workbook:

1. Intro (with a button to activate the paste macro)
2. Mock-up
3. Master
4. Client A
5. Lists

If there is a change to the 'Master' sheet I want to copy that across to Client A. I am able to achieve this by specifying the macro button to paste changes onto sheet 4.

My question is if I now add another sheet 'Client B':

1. Intro (with a button to activate the paste macro)
2. Mock-up
3. Master
4. Client A
5. Client B
6. Lists

How do I get the same macro button to paste into 'Client A' and 'Client B'(and Client C, D, etc. when added later)?

Comment: Isn't the addition of client B going to muck up your original 'paste macro' or is it robust enough that displacing the Lists worksheet isn't going to make a differebnce? For that matter, do the changes have to be reviewed before running the sub procedure? IOW, why aren't the values transferred directly  and immediately with a Worksheet_Change private sub?

Comment: It would help to see your code.